# php child class constructor called with parent object as parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, constructor

I am not that good yet on php syntax, so here is my question:

I have a class Foo.

Class Bar extends Foo.

I want to make a constructor for Bar that is called with an instance of class Foo as parameter, and make an instance of Bar that looks just like the instance of class Foo.

It seems I have to do this because Foo is a class in a WordPress plugin. I am writing a plugin to go on top of the original plugin, and in the filter I can add to, I get the Foo object.

I am open to doing this in the "right" way, if I can just learn the "right" way to do it.

so:

```
class Foo {      // in the original plugin
   public function __construct() {
       <do some stuff>
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {     // in my plugin to extend the original plugin
   public function __construct($myFooObject) {
      <I want: $this = $myFooObject; but it doesnt work>
      <do some stuff special to Bar>
   }
}
```

Comment: bar is extending foo, so it is ALREADY an instance of foo. it just happens to have the extra bar-bits layered on top.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but you might want to look into [parent::](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php). What Marc says is absolutely correct though.

Comment: The php manual has a really simple overview on exactly what you are asking. Here is a link to the documentation on it - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Yes, I know that bar is an instance of Foo, but I need all the content that was added when Foo was created. So my Bar is an instance of an "empty" Foo. Foo was created and manipulated quite a bit before I get a chance to do anything, so I need all the innards of the Foo instance that is passed to me. Variable contents, states of things, etc.

I can't just call parent::__construct() because of all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

class Bar extends Foo { // in my plugin to extend the original plugin
   public function __construct($myFooObject) {
     foreach (get_object_vars($myFooObject) as $key=>$value){
        $this->$key = $value;
     }

     // <I want: $this = $myFooObject; but it doesnt work>
     // <do some stuff special to Bar>
   }
}
```

This will not only instantiate with `Foo` properties, but copy `$myFooObject` Properties on creation.

Answer (score 1):

Well. You are already inheriting the features and members of the Foo class. What you just have missed to do here, is to call the parent class's constructor (Foo's constructor).

Add the following line to your Bar's `__construct()`:

```
parent::__constrcut();
```

Bar now looks like this:

```
class Bar extends Foo {     // in my plugin to extend the original plugin
   public function __construct($myFooObject) {
      parent::__construct(); // we've added this line to call the parent constructor
      <do some stuff special to Bar>
   }
}
```

Calling parent constructor in the child class constructor keeps the integrity of your objects and also allows the child class to have a dynamic access to its parent.

Comment: I agree this is the best option. But when the base class objects are constructed in a library this is not a solution.